# how to use multiple services in a single release

Tags: java, jenkins, microservices

I am using Microservices for a single release. Normally, I have a Version.json file which Jenkins gets the versions of microservices of each release and publish these multiple services.

Is there any other way to do it except using Version.json file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing single release with microservices is an anti-pattern. Therefore there is no ideal answer to your question.

If you want to get rid of one centralized `Version.json` file, I would suggest, keeping microservice version separate in each microservice project/repository. Qhen doing release Jenkins would just look into each released microservice repository and extract version from there. :)

Instead of `Version.json in Jenkins`:

```
{
  "microservice_a": "1.2.3",
  "microservice_b": "2.3.4"
}
```

You would have:
`Version.json in microservice_a repo`:

```
"1.2.3"
```

`Version.json in microservice_b repo`:

```
"2.3.4"
```

Comment: thanks for your  answer Simon. the problem is I want to make sure if some versions can work together. for example Microservice A might not work properly with Microservice B. I have to make sure if they can work together without any problem. Therefore I need such kind of a solution to say that A Microservice v1.1 can work properly with B Microservice 1.2. I hope you got what I meant

Comment: I see... Using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) would solve this problem. :) Other than that, what you are doing is fine and sometimes necessary (Unnamed car company does the same for their backend).